# Extjs adding a new element to a combobox store only in one view

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

Good day all.
I've a huge project done in EXTjs, on a specific view, there is a combobox to select countries, I'd like to add a new "virtual country" called "WW" (WorldWide), right after the store is loaded in this specific point only.

My first attempt was to add a listener to the store directly, but this added the new country on all views and all places the store is used, this was a big failure because other parts of the project aren't built to handle this virtual country.

So I'd like to add this new element directly where I have to use it, but I have some problems (I'm quite new to Ext and I'm getting into it very slowly).
actually I've come out with something like this:

```
tbar: [
        {
            xtype: 'adcombobox',
            displayField: 'name',
            id:'formCountry',
            reference: 'formcountry',
            valueField: 'id',
            store: 'Countries',
            value: 0,
            minChars: 0,
            queryMode: 'local',
            typeAhead: true,
            forceSelection: true,
            allowBlank: false,
            emptyText: 'Select a country',
            listConfig: {
                itemTpl: [
                    '<div><span class="" style="margin-right: 10px;"><img src="resources/flags/{id}.png"></span>{name}</div>'
                ]
            },
            listeners: {
                select: 'onCountrySelect',
                onLoad: function(store) {
                        store.insert(0, {
                            id:"ww",
                            shortCode: 'WW',
                            name: 'WorldWide'
                        });
                }
            }
        }
```

this does nothing.
I'm not sure if I'm calling the wrong event, or something...
Can someone help me on this? can you lead me to the right way?
I've also used the "load" event, without success.

UPDATE 1:

I've come with this solution at this moment:

```
listeners: {
                select: 'onCountrySelect',
                afterRender: function(store) {
                        this.getStore().insert(0, {
                            id:"ww",
                            shortCode: 'WW',
                            name: 'WorldWide'
                        });
                }
            }
```

that seems to make the trick, is it legit? My concern is to add this country "only once" so afterRender seems the right event to choose, as "load" is not present in the combobox (I've read it somewhere)..

Comment: I am not getting exactly, what do you mean by "only once"? whenever this code will run your record will always get inserted.

Comment: actually I was afraid to get a "worldwide" for each time the user opens the panel with the combobox, but it seems that the afterrender is fired only once, by the way, I'm getting only one worldwide country, and that's ok for now, I'm trying to figure out how to enhance the code, but actually this is doing the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you add it to the store, it is in the store, and all views and components bound to the store will use the country.

If you need stores with slightly different data, I can only recommend using [`ChainedStore`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.data.ChainedStore.html).

The main limitation that you have to be aware of is that in a Chained Store, you can filter out data that is still available in the source; you cannot add data.

So you would start with a store that contains all data that should be shown anywhere, and then you filter out whatever you don't want to show in certain components/views:

```
Ext.define('AllCountries',{
    extend:'Ext.data.Store',
    storeId: 'AllCountries',
    inlineData:[{
        name: 'France',
        fictional: false
    },{
        name: 'Germany',
        fictional: false
    },{
        name: 'Middle-earth',
        fictional: true
    }]
});

Ext.define('FictionalCountries',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.ChainedStore',
    storeId: 'FictionalCountries',
    source: 'AllCountries',
    filters:[{
        filterFn:function(country) {
            return country.get('fictional');
        }
    }]
});

Ext.define('NonFictionalCountries',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.ChainedStore',
    storeId: 'NonFictionalCountries',
    source: 'AllCountries',
    filters:[{
        filterFn:function(country) {
            return !country.get('fictional');
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: unfortunately, I cannot alter the store data, so I have no possibility to add a new field to the data to filter it out.